# ASP.NET - Trailing Slash and Tilde

Tags: asp.net

I've found what seems like a bizarre problem with IIS 6.0 and .NET 3.5. I always use the tilde for all URLs (eg: ~/mypage.aspx) so if I go to mydomain.com/mypage.aspx, everything works fine. If, however, I add a trailing slash and go to mydomain.com/mypage.aspx/, all links on the page which use the tilde get rendered as mydomain.com/mypage.aspx/otherpage.aspx instead of mydomain.com/otherpage.aspx.

This happens with all controls.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: `mydomain.com/mypage.aspx/` is a wrong URL. And I think it is working as expected.

Comment: If it already works fine, why trying the wrong URL? Slashes are to specify what's inside the current folder. If you could write such a question, you certainly know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mydomain.com/mypage.aspx/` is a wrong URL. By this URL it will look for `mypage.aspx` sub-directory. And I think it is working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to put a slash at the end of the page name. Why do you put that slash? The slash means a folder in the application.

Comment: It was reported by a client, not something I'd ever have though of or tried. As long as I'm not missing anything.